# Auth guard [:superAdmin] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel

am creating a custom guard for the admin and am  getting the error "auth guard is not defined"
i have tried "php artisan config:clear and php artisan config cache" but still the error. i wonder what i am doing wrong.

#### Here is my auth config

```
    <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |


  | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'SuperAdmin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'superAdmin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------


 |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
            
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |


  | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
```

| Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
| times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
| confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
|
*/

```
'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

];

#### AdminController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('auth::superAdmin');
}


/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('admin');
}
```

}

#### AdminLoginController

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\auth;
use auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('guest:superAdmin', ['Except' => ['logout']]);
}
public function showLoginForm()
{
        return view('auth.adminLogin');

    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // validate the input from the admin
        $this->validate($request, 
        ['email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
        //  attempt admin to log in
        if(auth::guard('superAdmin')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password], $request->get('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }
        //if unsucessfull take them back to the login page
        return redirect()->withInput($reuest->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: it would be `auth:SuperAdmin` as the middleware ... `{middleware name}:{parameters}`

Comment: thanks that is correct.... when you getting exhausted you can't see such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guard is `SuperAdmin`, not `superAdmin`